# creating jquery effect to show new page in same screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

In some of the website I found header and footer remains fixed.

When user click on any link in header or footer then new page opens from downside(or any other way) on same window.

I dont remember exactly the link for such site. I appreciate if someone can show me how that work.

**I know how to open new page without page reload using ajax. But dont know how to create attractive effect which web developer creates.**

I google it but could not think correct words to get this exactly.

Comment: That would normally be related to retrieving the page using AJAX call and then injecting it (manually) into the container on your current page, while also taking care of cleanup and proper URL updating to reflect such a transition in history.

Comment: @ZenMaster: thanks, can you please show me some example or how to create such a affect. I know how to open new page in same window without page reload

Comment: @nnnnnn: I already new ajax and jquery methods to load new page. But on button click open new page and showing effect like new page is comming from downword side is different dude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do know how to navigate (just in case - here is an example: [AJAX navigation](http://tutorialzine.com/2009/09/simple-ajax-website-jquery/)), but need to see examples of navigation "styling", Codrops would be a great place to start:

[Codrops - navigation examples](http://tympanus.net/codrops/?s=navigation)

[Codrops - page transitions](http://tympanus.net/codrops/?s=page%20transitions)

Comment: thanks, nice link. but still looking for my requirement.

Comment: Well, the link above have any page transition you'd imagine, you just have to go through the links.

Answer (score 1):

> *"I know how to open new page without page reload using ajax. But dont know how to create attractive effect which web developer creates."*

The simplest method is to have a container div within which you put the variable content (i.e., the current "page"):

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

(When your page is *first* loaded that div can have default content as appropriate, it doesn't have to start empty.)

Then using the Ajax method of your choice (that you mention you already know how to use), in the success handler you then use an animation method to hide that main div, then change its content to the html returned via ajax, then show the div again using the animation method of your choice:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'yourUrlHere.com',
    success : function(newContent) {
        $("#content").fadeOut(1000, function() {
            $(this).html(newContent).slideDown(1000);
        });
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/M4ZZ6/

From there you can get as fancy with the transition as you like by applying [different animation effects](http://api.jqueryui.com/category/effects/). Or use a page transition plugin...

Answer (score 1):

If you want the easy way check this.

```
<div id='loadpage' style='display:none'></div>
```

---

Jquery code:

```
$('#loadpage').load('mypage.php',function(){$('#loadpage').fadeIn(300);});
```

---

You can add more efects for your loads.

Here is the example.
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CaptKnee/96E9j/1/)

Comment: yw, I'm glad to do it. It works, just for your own php files. (: